# Azure Kubernetes Services - how to choose which containers (Windows or Linux) and OS should be setup on Nodes?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, containers, azure-aks

during the AKS cluster creation/configuration I do not see option to specify if we will be using the Linux or Windows containers and according to that to choose OS system which will be installed on the Nodes for containers? How is this being configured/selected?

Thanks

Comment: How do you create the cluster?

Comment: Check [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli#add-a-windows-server-node-pool)

Comment: @timsmelik Hi, thanks for the answer but I do not get it - so it means that Linux node pool is by default created and I can only "...add an additional node pool" that will be Windows??? Wow.... I am really hoping I didn't understand it properly... but since they state "additional" it seems Linux node is required..

Comment: @AmitBaranes I am creating it through the Azure Portal or through the AZ CLI. With templates I am not so skilled

Comment: @timsmelik I really seem this as problematic since we are in test and dev phase and we do not care about redundacy of having at least 2 nodes and similar... but they stated "..alongside the Linux node pool." so it means I do need to have 2 node pools which probably means with 1 node minimum per pool which means 2 nodes in total but I do not need Linux node... I am still feeling very surprised and confused, does it really work like this?

Comment: From the docs : "All AKS clusters are created with a default first node pool, which is Linux-based. This node pool contains system services, which are needed for the cluster to function. It's recommended to run at least two nodes in the first node pool to ensure reliability of your cluster and the ability to do cluster operations. The first Linux-based node pool can't be deleted unless the AKS cluster itself is deleted."

Comment: @AmitBaranes thanks Amit I didn't know that. How many nodes does this Linux node pool have by default? 0 or 1? If I create AKS with additional Windows Node Pool with Node count 1 and for Linux default node pool I do not set anything for how many nodes I will be charged by the AKS? for 1 or 2? of course asking this because of the pricing and costs since only Nodes are being charged. Thank you

Comment: What is the minimum number of nodes that I need to have for that default Node pool? 0 or 1? I personally do not need any Linux nodes that is why I am asking what is the minimum for that required Linux Node pool... sorry for lot of questions, it's really confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-faq#can-i-run-windows-only-clusters-in-aks):

> All AKS clusters are created with a default first node pool, which is
> Linux-based. This node pool contains system services, which are needed
> for the cluster to function. It's recommended to run at least two
> nodes in the first node pool to ensure reliability of your cluster and
> the ability to do cluster operations. The first Linux-based node pool
> can't be deleted unless the AKS cluster itself is deleted.

With that been said.. you must have at least 1 node group which is Linux based.

Comment: thanks Amit I didn't know that. How many nodes does this Linux node pool have by default? 0 or 1? If I create AKS with additional Windows Node Pool with Node count 1 and for Linux default node pool I do not set anything -- for how many nodes in total I will be charged by the AKS? for 1 or 2? of course asking this because of the pricing and costs since only Nodes are being charged. Thank you

Comment: as I mentioned I do not care about redundancy in this phase... I just need minimum of minimum because of the costs since it is just development but I do need Windows node!!!

Comment: You can specify the node count from the CLI using `--node-count `(default value: 3 ) Regarding the Windows node pool.. you will be charged on the amount of node that you create :)

Comment: What is the minimum number of nodes that I need to have for that default Node pool? 0 or 1? I personally do not need any Linux nodes that is why I am asking what is the minimum for that required Linux Node pool... sorry for lot of questions, it's really confusing

Comment: 1 node is the minimum since this node pool contains system services, which are needed for the cluster to function.